How can we prove that the $ L^2\left(S^1\right) $ defined below is a ring?
Problem: Let $S^1=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ is a infinite group under multiplication. A given real-valued function $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called square integrable if $\sum_{z\in S^1} f^2(z)$ exists and is finite. The set of all measurable square integrable functions $S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is denoted by $L^2\left(S^1\right)$. Can we show that $L^2\left(S^1\right)$ is a ring under pointwise addition and convolution multiplication as follows?
\begin{align*}
    (f * g)(z):=\sum_{y \in S^1} f(y) g\left(y^{-1} z\right).
\end{align*}
If this result cannot be proven, what conditions can be added about $ \sum_{z \in S^1} $ to make this conclusion hold?
I have made some attempts. For any $ f, g, h \in L^2\left(S^1\right) $, we have
$$\begin{align*}
    \sum_{z\in S^1}(f+g)^2(z)&\le 2\sum_{z\in S^1}\left(f^2+g^2\right)(z)\\
&=2\sum_{z\in S^1}f^2(z)+2\sum_{z\in S^1}g^2(z)\\
&\lt +\infty.
\end{align*}$$
which shows that $ f + g \in L^2\left(S^1\right) $. Note that zero function is the additive identity of $ L^2\left(S^1\right) $ and $ -f $ is the additive inverse of $ f $ in $L^2\left(S^1\right)$, thus $ \left( L^2\left(S^1\right), + \right) $ is an abelian group. I first tried to use the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality to prove the closure of the convolution operation, but I failed.
$$\begin{align*}
    \sum_{z\in S^1}(f*g)^2(z)&=\sum_{z\in S^1}\left(\sum_{y\in S^1} f(y) g\left(y^{-1} z\right)\right)^2 \\
&\le \sum_{z\in S^1} \left(\sum_{y\in S^1}f^2(y)\right)\left(\sum_{y\in S^1}g^2(y^{-1}z)\right)\\
    &=\sum_{z\in S^1} \left(\sum_{y\in S^1}f^2(y)\right)\left(\sum_{y\in S^1}g^2(y)\right)\\
&=+\infty.
\end{align*}$$
I think this problem requires measure theory to solve. Thanks to anyone who provides any hints or assistance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra_of_a_locally_compact_group#The_convolution_algebra_L1(G)

Since $S^1$ is a continuum, don't you mean $$\int\limits_{S^1} dz$$ instead of $\sum\limits_{z \in S^1}$?

I like to think of these in terms of Fourier coefficients.  If $f \in L^2(S^1) = L^2([0,1])$, you have
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n e^{2\pi i nx} \tag{$x \in [0,1]$}$$
where
$$c_n = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2\pi i nx}dx.$$
The condition that $f$ lie in $L^2(S^1)$ is equivalent to the condition that $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z}|c_n|^2 < \infty$.
Anyway, it is not difficult to see that if
$$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_n e^{2\pi i nx} $$
and
$$g(x) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} d_n e^{2\pi i nx} $$
then
$$f \ast g(x) = \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} c_nd_n e^{2\pi i nx}$$
and you just need to check that $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} |c_nd_n|^2 < \infty$.
